# Use a constant in a promise nested in a Promise.all([])

Tags: javascript, promise

Any idea why I am getting the following error on this code?

```
notification.provider#sendNewEventNotification - Could not send notification for new event: ReferenceError: sport is not defined
```

It looks like it is due to the call of `sport` in the promise nested in the `Promise.all`.

If I `console.log` the `sport` just before `Promise.all` I can see a sport.

I am wondering why this error is occurring and why only for sport...

```
const sendNewEventNotification = function(eventId, eventObj, company) {
  const sport = eventObj.sport;
  const timestampStarts = eventObj.timestampStarts;
  const timestampEnds = eventObj.timestampEnds;
  const title = eventObj.title;
  const location = eventObj.location.main_text;
  const ownerId = eventObj.owner;
  const additionalData = {eventId};

  return Promise.all([
    userProvider.getUserFirstname(ownerId, company),
    retrieveNotificationIds(sport, company, ownerId)
  ])
  .then(results => {
    const ownerFirstname = results[0];
    const notificationIds = results[1];

    // ** Prepare notification
    const notifDateTime = moment(timestampStarts).format('dddd Do MMMM YYYY') + ' ('
      + moment(timestampStarts).format('HH:mm') + '-'
      + moment(timestampEnds).format('HH:mm') + ')';

    const title = `#${sport} - Nouvelle session disponible !`;
    const body = `...`;

      return {title, body, additionalData, notificationIds};
    })
    .then(({title, body, additionalData, notificationIds}) => {
      let notificationData = prepareNotificationData(title, body, additionalInfo, notificationIds);
      return sendNotification(notificationData);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`notification.provider#sendNewEventNotification - Could not send notification for new event: ${error}`));
}
exports.sendNewEventNotification = sendNewEventNotification;
```

Comment: Seems like a typo `additionalInfo` vs `additionalData`

Comment: Sorry the error was regarding `sport` (I updated the error in my original post)

Comment: Not defined where exactly?

Comment: Change your `catch` block into `.catch(console.log)` so you can see where exactly `sport` is not defined

Comment: You should log the error object directly, so that you will see the line number and the call stack. The above code looks correct so I would guess that the problem is in one of the functions you call.

Comment: You are right. The problem is from an inner function. It might be better that I delete the post, what do you think? But one important question, why `console.log` directly in the catch give more details than `console.log` the error?